# Нет интернета со статическим ip Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

На CentOS 8 такие настройки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=eui64
NAME=ens160
UUID=da76b79a-625a-4d04-9d98-a5d94c11fed7
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.88
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
IPV6_DISABLED=yes
```

Содержимое /etc/resolve.conf

```
search home.dom
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

CentOS запущена как Виртуальная машина. Сеть настроена как Bridged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так,ну вроде разобрался. Неправильный DNS указывал. Надо было 192.168.1.254